# ngValue returning index and value

Tags: angular

The value coming back from a select using [ngValue] is a concatenation of index and value

if I use this

```
<select (change)="selectType($event)" name="type" >
    <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type.value" >{{type.display}}</option>
</select>
```

and then I use this to get the value of the selected option

```
selectType (e) {
    this.type = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

My values look like this

```
0: type1
1: type2
2: type3
...
```

how would I just get the value?
It seems ngValue is putting the index AND value in the value parameter.

Comment: I suggest you to use reactiveforms to handle your form, you going to be able to subscribe on change of your form object

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are handling the `change` DOM event, the parameter `$event` is the [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) supplied by the DOM, not the value of the option set with `ngValue`.

If you handled the `ngModelChange` Angular event instead, the parameter `$event` would be the value of the option. You could also use two-way binding with `ngModel` if you only need to set the value of `type` in the component class.

Here are the various options. You can try them in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxkktf).

1. Passing the value of the event target to `selectType`:

```
    <select (change)="selectType($event.target.value)" name="type">
```

2. Setting the value with two-way binding using `ngModel` (without `selectType`):

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="type" name="type">
```

3. Handling `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` separately (if more processing is done in `selectType`):

```
    <select [ngModel]="type" (ngModelChange)="selectType($event)" name="type">
```

Comment: how can I send it external model if I use two-way binding (solution 2)?
 e.g.:
when I use it with parent model <custom-select [(ngModel)]="parentValue"></custom-select> update the parentValue model with concatenation of index and value. :(

Comment: Agree, it does not reply the question. I am also stuck with the select which needs two-way binding and has a NUMBER value (not a STRING). Additional problem: the chosen option is not selected.